# Code to Hyperlink the Files With the Items Present in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small query. I have some values in Column A whose image is attached.

[image]

I have some files located in say D:\Software Work\Important Files\
The file names are exactly the same name mentioned in column A.

I want to hyperlink the cell value to the corresponding file stored in location.

The image of the storage of files is also attached.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub mymacro()
Dim objcreate As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("C1")


Set objcreate = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objcreate.GetFolder(rng)
i = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'select cell
Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select
'create hyperlink in selected cell
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    objFile.Path, _
    TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Code is working fine except one thing. It is populating the file name along with the extension. I only want the filename except extension.
Kindly advise.
Thanks
Salman

Comment: No need for code, just go to the Insert Ribbon, Hyperlink...navigate to the file...click ok.  If you have a lot of them...use the macro recorder to get you started.

Comment: I have lot of items in column A. With Macro reader it goes one by one. I am looking to run a loop to hyperlink the items...

Comment: Exactly, use the macro recorder to learn how to do it for one, and then loop it.  SO is not a code writing service, we are here to help each other through specific issues and errors.  When you have some code and a specific question...you can post your code and we can help you work through it.

Comment: @Rdster i have written the code. But a small query is there which i have mentioned in the post. Can you please help me out in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, and much more.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/download/

Download and run the file from the link named 'File Manager (Excel Workbook)'.  Post back if you have any additional questions.